# PackagePlugin for swift 5.6 not found

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to check the new swift 5.6 Additional Package Plugin APIs but Xcode is not able to find the `PackagePlugin` library. Has anybody faced a similar issue?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find out a solution?